# Do we need a kunyomi tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed yesterday that there was a onyomi tag, but not a kunyomi tag.  Is there a reason for that, or is that just an oversight?

If it is on purpose, can someone help me understand why?  I'd be interested to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [onyomi](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onyomi) tag is primarily used on questions that involve different types of *on'yomi*. (I would consider [Did I determine the pronunciation of 人口 correctly?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36894/1628) a typical question for this tag.)

This is also mentioned in the tag wiki of [onyomi](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onyomi):

> 音読み. A Sino-Japanese reading of kanji. Usually divided into 呉音 "Wu sound", 漢音 "Han sound", 唐音 "Tang sound", and 慣用音; the first three for readings imported from the corresponding Chinese dynasties, the last for exceptional readings.

There are no such ambiguities for *kun'yomi*. Questions about *kun'yomi* are usually about etymology and thus tagged [etymology](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology).

---

The tagging system is ever evolving and improvements are always welcome. If you think that a tag (for example [kunyomi](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kunyomi)) might be useful, you can start a meta discussion in which you explain why it is a useful tag and find at least a handful of questions that would fit this tag.

Comment: I see the logic here, and I have to admit that I agree.  There is less ambiguity with kun'yomi to be sure.  Thanks for clearing that up.  Personally, I don't see a huge need for either tag when there is the `readings` tag, but given what you said, I could understand why someone might want to include the on'yomi tag as well.